# netplan generate: `gateway4` has been deprecated, use default routes instead

Tags: route, netplan

When using `netplan generate` I kept on getting an error message:

> `gateway4` has been deprecated, use default routes instead.

For static IP address assignments in netplan, I've always used the structure:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
      - 192.168.10.10/24
      gateway4: 192.168.10.1
      nameservers:
      addresses: [192.168.10.1]
```

Obviously `gateway4` is referencing `gateway4: 192.168.10.1`, but how do we fix it?

Comment: Invalid YAML: inconsistent indentation:
it seems like the addresses, routes, and nameservers fields should be at the same level of indentation as the dhcp4 and dhcp6 fields under ethernets. However, they are currently indented one level too much.

Comment: you're right, the indentation was inconsistent. thanks, @spaceman117X... I've edited to [hopefully] correct that.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The current syntax to replace `gateway4` is `routes` with `to` and `via`.

For the netplan above based on the `192.168.10.0/24` network, it would be:

```
            routes:
                - to: default
                  via: 192.168.10.1
```

So the whole config would be:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
     addresses:
      - 192.168.10.10/24
     routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.10.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [192.168.10.1]
```

Currently there's a very good reference full of practical examples at:
https://netplan.io/examples/

One other tip when working on netplan files, `yamllint` can save you a lot of trouble.

```
sudo apt install yamllint
sudo dnf install yamllint
sudo pacman -S yamllint
```

For example, I introduced a small formatting error:

```
      - to: default
      via: 192.168.10.1
```

Then when I run `yamllint`, I'll get a line number that should help track down where the errors are.

```
yamllint /etc/netplan/01-netplan.yaml
```

```
28:9      error    syntax error: expected <block end>, but found '?' (syntax)
```

If you have any syntax errors (for example spacing issues) yamllint will give you the line numbers of your problems.

Hopefully this has made your `netplan generate` and `netplan apply` go smoothly!

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan --debug apply
```

Comment: notice how 'to' is vertically aligned wth 'via'. You will get a parsing error if indentation is not correct. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247535/yaml-how-many-spaces-per-indent).

Comment: @simonpa71 So you think that the `via` line for my gateway is actually being ignored but the default value is somehow working for me anyway? That's very possible. I did check with yamllint and I'm not getting a warning, but that doesn't mean it's wrong. Unfortunately it's a production machine for me, so not convenient to experiment... If you have a precise correction very happy to make it here and help others save time! Thanks for your support!

Comment: on the contrary, I'm sure your solution is correct and working fine. In my attempts, I made the mistake of aligning 'via' with the '-' (minus bfore the 'to') and got a bunch of errors. Your suggestion of using yamllint is also on spot, and would have saved me some trial and error.

Comment: @erwin Can you please provide your answer with a simple `yamllint` usage ?

Comment: @SebMa please see the updated version