# How to solve "gateway4 has been deprecated" error when using 'netplan'?

Tags: ubuntu, netplan

I tried to generate a static IP address using netplan in Ubuntu jammy. When I type in

```
sudo netplan apply
```

this was the result

```
** (generate:41329): WARNING **: 16:53:17.169: `gateway4` has been deprecated, use default routes instead.
See the 'Default routes' section of the documentation for more details.

** (process:41327): WARNING **: 16:53:17.379: `gateway4` has been deprecated, use default routes instead.
See the 'Default routes' section of the documentation for more details.
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question and show your configuration. This might be a duplicate, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/681220/330217

Comment: Does this answer your question? [netplan generate: \`gateway4\` has been deprecated, use default routes instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681220/netplan-generate-gateway4-has-been-deprecated-use-default-routes-instead)