# Convert unusual Netplan config to avoid deprecated Gateway4 field

Tags: networking, ip, routing, netplan

I have an existing `01-netcfg.yaml` file from documentation which is supposed to have worked previously.

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: []212.80.140.1/32]
      gateway4: 62.210.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [62.210.16.6, 62.210.16.7]
      routes:
      - to: 62.210.0.1/32
        via: 212.80.140.1
        scope: link
```

This config is for a secondary or failover IP4 in a Virtual Machine inside a hypervisor (Proxmox PVE) on the [Scaleway network](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/dedibox-network/network/how-to/configure-network-netplan/).

I cannot any longer use the Gateway4 field in Netplan on Ubuntu 22.04. Running `netplan apply` fails with the error:

```
gateway4 has been deprecated, use default routes instead
```

I believe I must update the syntax to use the `routes` field instead of `gateway4` but I cannot get the syntax right. The default gateway is outside of the subnet of the main address so it needs additional configuration. Maybe onlink, source routing, routing tables etc. I don't know.

[http://people.ubuntu.com/~slyon/netplan-docs/examples/#reaching-a-directly-connected-gateway](http://people.ubuntu.com/%7Eslyon/netplan-docs/examples/#reaching-a-directly-connected-gateway)

Can anyone convert the given config to use `routes` etc. instead of `gateway4`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [netplan generate: \`gateway4\` has been deprecated, use default routes instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681220/netplan-generate-gateway4-has-been-deprecated-use-default-routes-instead)

Comment: "I have an existing 01-netcfg.yaml file from documentation which is supposed to have worked previously." – That file isn't even valid YAML, let alone a valid Netplan. It most certainly has never worked.

Comment: Thanks guys. Jorg - if you think the example isn't valid YAML you might offer an actual reason why it's not valid YAML.

Comment: larsks - I've looked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681220/netplan-generate-gateway4-has-been-deprecated-use-default-routes-instead and it covers the basics of removing gateway4, but nothing about my specific case, which is a default gateway address which is outside of the subnet network of the primary IP4. There is nothing specific online for that which I have yet found.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to set the "onlink" flag (`on-link: true`) on your default route:

| networkd | Netplan (best effort attempt) |
| --- | --- |
| ``` [Route] Gateway=62.210.0.1 GatewayOnLink=yes ``` | ``` routes: - via: 62.210.0.1 on-link: true ``` |

Adding a local /32 route is an alternative (you usually don't need<sup>1</sup> to do both). Your example shows the BSD way of doing it (routing via own IP address), but on Linux it would be more conventional to define a route *without* a gateway. (Scope only needs to be specified with older networkd versions that get it wrong.)

| networkd | netplan (attempt at guessing the syntax) |
| --- | --- |
| ``` [Route] Destination=62.210.0.1/32 Scope=link [Route] # Destination=0.0.0.0/0 Gateway=62.210.0.1 ``` | ``` routes: - to: 62.210.0.1 scope: link - via: 62.210.0.1 ``` |

---

<sup>1</sup> (The docs you found are slightly outdated; as of kernel 4.17 the "onlink" flag works properly for IPv6 too. The separate /128 route was only needed because older kernels ignored the flag.)